# Try catch going wrong

Tags: java, try-catch

im creating another method that calls a method of another class. after surrounding with a try catch netbeans keeps telling me "cant find symbol: variable tLoad" what am i doing wrong?

```
public Track trackLoader(String fileName) {

    try {
        Track tLoad = TrackReader.read(fileName);


    } catch (IOException | FormatException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RailwayModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 

        return tLoad;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare `tLoad` outside the `try`-block to use it outside of it.

```
public Track trackLoader(String fileName) {
    Track tLoad = null;
    try {
        tLoad = TrackReader.read(fileName);


    } catch (IOException | FormatException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RailwayModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 

        return tLoad;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `tLoad` lives only in `try` block, not even in catch, and definitely not after them. Fixed:

```
   public Track trackLoader(String fileName) {
       Track tLoad = null;
        try {
            tLoad = TrackReader.read(fileName);
    } catch (IOException | FormatException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RailwayModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 

        return tLoad;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The jls explains this pretty well:

> The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4) is the rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its own initializer and including any further declarators to the right in the local variable declaration statement. [jls 6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

A try-catch-block is defined as:

> TryStatement:
>       try Block Catches
>       try Block Catchesopt Finally
>       TryWithResourcesStatement

from [jls 14.20](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20).

So in your code

```
try {
    Track tLoad = TrackReader.read(fileName); //<-- this variable

    //is only visible until here
} catch (IOException | FormatException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(RailwayModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} 

    return tLoad;
}
```

Since `tload` is only visible until the end of the `try-block`, the return-statement doesn't make any sense. Instead you could try something like this:

```
Track tLoad = null;

try {
    tLoad = TrackReader.read(fileName);
} catch (IOException | FormatException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(RailwayModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} 

    return tLoad;
}
```